# Choose t-test or ANOVA for personalized ad effectiveness within each cohort?

Tags: anova, python, t-test, marketing

I've got 10 cohorts(determined by ML clustering) of customers I can target for customer personalization ads.

The experimental design is that I send out a known standard personal ad(based on cohort characteristics) to each cohort treatment group and a standard ad to all cohort control groups. A random 100k customers are chosen each within each cohort for treatment & control. I'm trying to measure lift(conversion rate increase) as a result of personalization within each cohort & across all cohorts.

Would I use separate t-tests to assess the effectiveness of the personalized ads within each group or ANOVA?

Thanks!